# Deny from all not working for pdf and images

Tags: php, .htaccess, pdf

My website allows users to uploads files (typically pdf, jpg, etc.).

The objective is to block website users from directly accessing the uploaded files which are stored in https://sub.domain.com/folder/upload/ but still allow certain password protected `.php` pages to access the files.

The below code correctly gives a 403 errors for `.php` files but not for `.pdf` and `.png` (these are the only files types tested so far). The `.pdf` and `.png` files are previewed in the browser (which I suspect may be the cause of the issue).

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

Below are a list of trouble shooting attempts that I have tried so far:

1. Removed all other items from the .htaccess file
2. Cleared Cache's/tried incognito/tried other browsers
3. Switch between `order allow,deny` and `order deny,allow`
4. Modified `AllowOverride` in htaccess
5. Disabled `Options -MultiViews` in htaccess
6. Tried put htaccess in both `https://sub.domain.com/folder/upload/` and `https://sub.domain.com/`
7. Tried numerous different code blocks from online with minor variations e.g. capitalisation
8. Specified `<Files>` by type (`.pdf`) and also tried to specify files (`file.pdf`)
9. Force a redirection (instead of deny access) and had the same result i.e. it works for `.php` but not for `.pdf` and `.png`

A few things to note that may help with fixes:

1. I am using Siteground as my hosting service
2. Other .htaccess commands works normally e.g. password protection/forcing https

Please let me know if you need any additional detail.

Thanks,

Comment: Move the files to a folder that is outside the web root. PHP will still have access but there will be no way for users to browse to them.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to this problem would be to actually store the files outwith the web accessible folder (usually www but depends on how your hosting is configured).

For files to be accessible to a PHP script on the same server they do not have to reside in a web accessible directory, however, if I understand you correctly I beleive what you mean to say is that the files should be downloadable by a user that logs in and access a particular PHP script.

If this is the case, if you store the files outwith the web accessible path, of course links to the files would no longer exist.

You could get around this by:

1. Instead of pointing to the file directly, point to a PHP script
2. The PHP script would first check the user is authorised to access the file in some way.
3. if authorised output the relevant headers for the file type
4. Read the content of the file and stream this to the user.

To the user this would act like a normal download link.